# EclipseLink 1.2 and BatchFetch

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have run into a EclipseLink issue with multiple queries running against the DB instead of a single query. I found the below SO threads which provides @BatchFetch annotation solution to help run as one master query

[How to do join fetching instead of select fectching with EclipseLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678784/how-to-do-join-fetching-instead-of-select-fectching-with-eclipselink)

[How to define the EclipseLink annotation for the following?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284778/how-to-define-the-eclipselink-annotation-for-the-following)

But I am using EclipseLink 1.2 and the above annotation's classes are only supported by EclipseLink 2+. Appreciate if you could please help with an alternate solution for 1.2. I tried migrating the entire project to EclipseLink 2 but am running into mapping issues which I have no patience to fix right now.

I am using EclipseLink's JPA

Comment: +1 on the question.  Well written.  Good evidence of work on your part.  Sorry I don't have the answer.

Comment: JPA1.2 doesn't exist. JPA1.0 exists, JPA2.0 exists, JPA2.1 is in planning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @BatchFetch annotation just set the mapping to use batch reading.  You can do this in EclipseLink 1.2 using a DescriptorCustomizer and using the ForeignReferenceMapping API.

Comment: In addition to QueryHint BATCH, I set the join columns to FETCH LAZY and also used Foreign Reference API's @JoinFetch(JoinFetchType.OUTER). We are not using any pagination, getting back the correct results

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a query hint, for example:

```
    query.setHint(QueryHints.BATCH, "c.sourceTable");
```

In this case the `sourceTable` relation for all `c`'s will be loaded with a single query, not one per `c`.

Comment: @unbelli : thx for the response, I tried both  @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.BATCH, value = "c.sourceTable") and query.setHint(QueryHints.BATCH, "c.sourceTable") before posting here. Observe multiple queries running against the DB for sourceTable join. It is like I've hit a brick-wall here

Comment: well, post some code and we can fix it. query.setHint works for me.